# Confusing Disk Space Situation

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, disk, disk-usage

My system primarily has Windows 7 on it. A while ago, I switched from VirtualBoxing into Linux to installing Linux in its own Partition. I thought I had **lots** of free space.

However, Ubuntu's now telling me about not having enough space.
Now I can see that I have a folder called "host", taking up 87% of my hard drive, which, to my surprise, seems to be my Windows Partition.

So, let me see if I understand this correctly: The amount of space I allocated for Ubuntu was slightly larger than the amount of Space I was using on my `C:` drive, and now fate has caught up with me?

Does this make sense? How do I fix this? What I have done?

This is the output of `df -H`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       19G   18G   20M 100% /
udev            2.0G  4.1k  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           801M  934k  800M   1% /run
none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none            2.1G  164k  2.1G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda4       377G  130G  247G  35% /host
overflow        1.1M   13k  1.1M   2% /tmp
/dev/sda3       108G   82G   26G  77% /media/12842F85842F6A85
```

Comment: Would you mind pasting the output of df -H to this item? It would help us understand the situation more.

Comment: @Mordoc Edited/Pasted as requested! :)

Comment: So what is actually is complaining about is the root or "/" which is mounted from /dev/loop0. Are you booting from an .iso or a USB stick? /dev/loop is usually an .iso mounted within the filesystem...

Comment: The other thought is this, did you install Ubuntu from inside Windows (wubi.exe installer)?

Comment: I am not booting from a USB but...
I may in fact have used Wubi... I know I at least considered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you used Wubi to install Ubuntu within Windows.

To remedy this you can back up any data you have on your Ubuntu partition, uninstall Ubuntu (Via "Add and Remove Program" in Windows) make a live disc if you don't have one made, boot off the disc, and walk through the installer... it should help you partition your drive.

Comment: Oi vei. Thanks folks (@Mordoc and @Gui) for your help!

I'll try this and report back!

Not sure how it took this long for it to bite me in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

The system (/) is installed on a 19GB partition.

Go to System monitor -> 4th tab (filesystems) to check it. I would recommend 40GB+ the next time you install Ubuntu.